# Find previous "chokepoint" in path

Tags: algorithm, path, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, pseudocode

I have a "tree"-like structure of nodes and I'm trying to figure out an algorithm that will find previous "chokepoint" when end node is given. Here is a picture to better demonstrate:

[image]

- So when **15** is specified as end node I want to find **7**
- And if **7** is specified as end node I want to find **1**
- But in the example above if anything else than 7,15 or 16 is specified as end node the found node is the previous one since that is the only node connecting to the end node.

So the node I am searching for is the previous node that all paths must go through to get to the end node.

I tried an algorithm where I start from the end node and go backwards (using Breadth-first) and every node I find that has 2 or more outputs I add to a new list and nodes with one output I skip. For example in case with 15 as the end node, I end up adding 10 and 7 to list of potential nodes, but I'm not sure how to from there. Since I should not continue traversing from 7.

Is there potentially an algorithm out there that already does that and if not how could I achieve this?

Comment: yes, use biconnected components, the articulation points are your choke points

Comment: Does it work if my nodes have a direction? Since common way to find articulation points seems to be to run DFS first and then from the result graph find nodes that have children, but no connections to "ancestors".

Comment: nodes don't have directions. edges do. An undirected graph may be seen as a directed graph where there are two edges (both directions). I did not know about dominators from @matt timmermans . They seem to be closed to articulation points but not exactly. You should go for the proposed answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your "choke points" are what is commonly known as "dominators".  In a directed graph, one node X dominates another Y if all paths to Y must go through X.  In your graph, 1 and 7 dominate all greater nodes.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominator_(graph_theory)

The dominators of a directed graph form a tree.  The wikipedia article gives a simple algorithm for finding them all in quadratic time.

You can do it in linear time, but it's tricky.  The classic algorithm is from Lengauer and Tarjan.  You can find it here: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall03/cs528/handouts/a%20fast%20algorithm%20for%20finding.pdf

Comment: I looked through the simple but slower algorithm, but I'm not sure I understand what is happening in this part:

`while changes in any Dom(n)
     for each n in N - {n0}:
         Dom(n) = {n} union with intersection over Dom(p) for all p in pred(n)`

Comment: Yeah, that's a little tough to read.  It means for each node, remove any node from its dominator set, except itself, that isn't in the dominator sets of all its predecessors.  Then repeat for all nodes if anything changed.

Comment: Oh, ok got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) is an ordering of the graph such that each arrow agrees with the order.  For example in your example we might come up with the order:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 15
```

Do a topological sort using any of the `O(n)` algorithms for it.

Next, we walk the graph and track how many incoming edges each node has.

Finally we walk the graph in our sorted order and track how many edges we have seen one end of but not the other, and how many nodes have no incoming edges.  Any time we come to a node where all outgoing edges have not ended and every future node has incoming edges, that is a chokepoint.

After that, we can prepare two maps.  The first is from each node to its topological order.  The second is a balanced binary tree of where the chokepoints are.

The analysis in advance is `O(n)`.  The actual lookups are now `O(log(n))`.